# Cannot saveAndClose() GoogleDoc Api? Is there any other way to flush the update after batchUpdate?

Tags: node.js, rest, google-docs-api

I am new to coding and trying to create node.js server to copying and update document using google doc api and send back the link.

Everythings went well but my Doc take a while until it's update. I've search and realize that I need to saveAndClose() in order to flush the update but somehow I do not know how to code it without using DocumentApp. Is there any other way to flush the update after the batchUpdate?

```
const docs = google.docs({ version: 'v1', auth });

let requests = [
    {
        replaceAllText: {
            containsText: {
                text: '{{toWhom}}',
                matchCase: true,
            },
            replaceText: body.toWhom,
        },
    }
];

docs.documents.batchUpdate(
    {
        documentId: docId,
        resource: {
            requests,
        },
    }, (err, data) => {
        if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
        res.send(`https://docs.google.com/file/d/${docId}`);
        return(200);
    });
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your situation? I cannot understand about `my Doc take a while until it's update.`. What update did you do? Can you explain the detail information?

Comment: The Google Document in Google drive is suppost to replace the text '{{toWhom}}' with other value which it does but it take a while before the change show in Google Drive. For the few mins after run the code, the file remain unchange.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this situation. So in the current stage, I cannot propose the workaround and solution. I apologize for my poor skill.

Comment: I'm appreciated your help anyway. Thank you